# Elixir : any routine to force re-compilation?

Tags: elixir

I'm using EEx for mail templating...

I have integrated this on my module as follow:

```
defmodule Blackbox.ReportHandler do
  use GenServer

  import Swoosh.Email

  @email EEx.compile_file("web/templates/mail.html.eex")

  def init([actions: actions]) do
    {:ok, %{actions: actions, name: "none_yet", report: []}}
  end

[...]
  def handle_info({:test_step, :done, true}, s) do
    email = @email |> Code.eval_quoted([name: s.name, report: s.report]) |> elem(0)

    sent = new()
...
```

Since it compiles the EEx file when Blackbox.ReportHandler (i.e has changed), I need to either reload the module manually in the console, or change something on the ReportHandler module so it compiled again this time with an up-to-date EEx file.

Is there a way, to link ReportHandler's compilation to another file's modification ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@external_resource` module attribute is meant for exactly this:

> Specifies an external resource for the current module.
>
> Sometimes a module embeds information from an external file. This
>   attribute allows the module to annotate which external resources have
>   been used.
>
> Tools like Mix may use this information to ensure the module is
>   recompiled in case any of the external resources change.

<sup>[Source](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#module-external_resource)</sup>

So you need to just add this module attribute to make mix recompile the module if that file changes:

```
@external_resource "web/templates/mail.html.eex"
```

Comment: Wow, another one from @Dogbert... You answer so fast that I can't even accept it yet ! Thank you